# Judo throws which are defined as combinations of techniques?

Tags: technique, judo

Many judo techniques are defined as counters to attacks by uke ([*kaeshi-waza*](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/13280/definitions-of-judo-kaeshi-waza)). However *osoto-makikomi* is the only one I'm aware of that is described as a **combination** or sequence of techniques (*renzoku-waza*): a *soto-* or *uchi-makikomi* following a failed *osoto-gari/-otoshi/-guruma*.<sup>1</sup>

Are there any other judo techniques which are defined as combinations of other techniques?

---

1. "The final technique is *soto-makikomi*, but as it follows *osoto-gari*, the throw is called *osoto-makikomi.*"

- [Kodokan Judo Nage-waza - Various techniques and their names](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BbaUmMHLz4) (1994)

Comment: So the question is basically about special *names* for existing throws and its principles when applied as a follow-up technique on a failed or feinted different technique, like a de-ashi-barai, when used as a counter to de-ashi-barai is *called* trsubame-gaeshi although it technically is still a de-ash-barai?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking yep exactly, except with combinations of techniques instead of counters to techniques.

Comment: Minor remark: If I am not mistaken, combinations of throws are called Renraku-waza rather than Renzoku-waza.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few that are naturally a combination (Uchi-mata-makikomi following an Uchi-mata), but they can also be thrown directly. If you throw an O-soto-makikomi directly, without preceding O-soto-gari (or similar technique), then it is called Soto-makikomi.
If I have not overlooked anything, O-soto-makikomi is the only technique with this property.