# Definitions of judo kaeshi-waza

Tags: technique, judo

Many judo *kaeshi-waza* are not fundamentally different from other techniques, except that they are used as a counter to a specific attack by uke (e.g. *tsubame-gaeshi* is a *de-ashi-barai* used to counter a leg sweep). However there are many ways one can counter various attack attempts. Which counters are canonically considered *kaeshi-waza*?

Answer (score 2):

*Kodokan Judo nage-waza - Various techniques and their names* lists various counters falling under the kaeshi-waza technique names. For the counters to turning throws, they mostly consist of

1. *Kosoto-gari/ -gake* attacking uke's far (planted) foot/leg
2. Twisting uke continuing their forwards motion towards the left or right (*uki-otoshi*)

| Kaeshi-waza | Uke attack | Tori counter(s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tawara gaeshi | Ashi-dori / Morote-gari | (Tawara gaeshi) |
| Tsubame gaeshi | De- / Okuri-ashi-barai | De-ashi-barai |
| Osoto gaeshi | Osoto-gari | Osoto-gari |
| Uchi-mata sukashi | Uchi-mata | Uki-otoshi |
| Kouchi gaeshi | Kouchi-gari | Uki-otoshi |
| Ouchi gaeshi | Ouchi-gari | Uki-otoshi Kosoto-gari / -gake |
| Uchi-mata gaeshi | Uchi-mata | Kosoto-gari / -gake |
| Harai-goshi gaeshi | Harai-goshi | Kosoto-gari / -gake |
| Hane-goshi gaeshi | Hane-goshi | Kosoto-gari / -gake Ushiro-goshi |

Additionally there are the situational hip throws:

| Kaeshi-waza | Uke attack | Tori counter(s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Utsuri-goshi | Koshi-waza, uchi-mata etc | [Lift +] O-goshi |
| Ushiro-goshi | Koshi-waza | (Ushiro-goshi) |
| Daki-age | Do-jime / Guard | (Daki-age) |

---

**Note: Similarly named techniques**

While some other techniques have the word *kaeshi* in the name, I suspect these may be examples of the meaning of "reverse" as opposed to "counter [attack]" e.g. *kibisu-gaeshi, sumi-/obi-tori-/hikikomi-gaeshi* (in the same vein as [*ude-gaeshi*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhP3wL1yS2s)).